# Why it's not possible to %>% into return

Tags: r, magrittr

The function below attempts several ways to return after a pipe.

```
returnTry = function(){
    3 %>% return
    4 %>% return()
    5 %>% return(.)
    return(6)
    7
}
```

If I try to use this function however, all of the pipe attempts fail

```
> returnTry()
[1] 6
```

Why is this happening? I suspect it is about non standard evaluation happening within the pipe but can't pinpoint the exact cause.

As a bonus (disclaimer: I don't use this in my code. I don't recommend it's usage as it might reduce code readability), there is a "pipe" that works. The [bizarro pipe](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2017/01/using-the-bizarro-pipe-to-debug-magrittr-pipelines-in-r/).

```
returnTry = function(){
    3 %>% return
    4 %>% return()
    5 %>% return(.)
    6 ->.;return(.)
    return(7)
    8
}
```

returns 6.

Comment: see the issue here https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/32 for some discussion

Comment: Your "bizarro pipe" line seems misleading, the line break is disguised as a semi colon and no whitespace. It's not piping anything to `return`, it's just using `.` as an object name and then calling `return(.)` on the next line. It's equivalent to `6 -> x; return(x)`, or not using right-assignment, `6 <- .; return(.)`.

Comment: the 'bizarro pipe' isn't really a pipe at all. i'ts two statements separated by `;`. the first assigns into a variable `.` the seconde returnds `.`

Comment: My google-fu failed me. Interesting nonetheless

Comment: Bizarro pipe was a reference to the linked blog post. Quoted the "pipe" to emphasize the fakeness

Comment: It's about environments, you're returning from a child environment, pipes nest environments.

Comment: The "bizarro pipe" seems irrelevant to your question - I'm not sure why you mention it all. Yes, standard syntax built into base R works as expected, even if it is a little uncommon.

Comment: I think he mentioned it because it's the syntax that worked better to solve his real life issue, and it may be interesting to other users that wish to keep a "pipe-like" syntax in these cases.

Comment: In retrospect I see that it may be confusing. I thought I sufficiently separated it from the rest of the question with wording and obviously non-standard syntax. My motivation was to add a silly approach that works as expected as a contrast to the mainstream approach that does not. I am inclined to keep it there just so anyone who comes here in the future would know what the we were talking about in comments. Since the magrittr people have been considering a fix to the main question for 3 years now, anyone who comes here can be content, knowing there is a silly way "solve" their issue